# How do I add background dimming for alert or dialog android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

When I add an alert or dialog, I get only a shadow, not a complete blackout.

I tried to add setDim() but nothing helped. How do I add a darkening of the background that is outside the window. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfPdA.png).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.